# How to normalise a decimal into a number that is a value within a range

Tags: c++, c++11, math, integer-arithmetic

How can I normalise a floating point decimal *in the range [0.0, 1.0]* to become a number that is set between a range of max and min value? Is normalise the right word? Following what I want to do.

If I input `0.5` and the range is `0` to `10`, then the output should be `5`.

If I input `0.799999` and the range is `0` to `10`, then the output should be `8`.

If I input `0.345` and the range is `0` to `10`, then the output should be `3`.

If I input `0.555` and the range is `0` to `20`, then the output should be `11`.

```
unsigned int Normalise(float value, unsigned int min, unsigned int max) {
    // Return value normalised between min and max
}
```

I am not super sure if *normalise* is the right word for this in arithmetic context.

Comment: looks like you want the absolute value of value * max.

Comment: I'd call the inverse operation normalization. (The normalization of a (mathematical) vector results in a vector of length 1.) This operation should not be too hard though `(max - min) * value + min` and some casting/rounding should be sufficient.

Comment: What should the output be if the input is `0.05`? Should it be `5` or `1`?

Comment: `0.05` should be 0 because it is not above `0.5`

Comment: @fabian `(max - min) * value + min` seems to do the trick. Nice!

Comment: the term is changing **dynamic range** of signal and you can use **linear interpolation** for that just like the answers suggest ... `x = x0 + (X-X0)*(x1-x0)/(X1-X0)` where `X,X0,X1` is input value and range and `x,x0,x1` is output value and range

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the question to point out that the decimal floating point must be in the range [0.0, 1.0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "Interpolation" a.k.a "Linear Interpolation" a.k.a `lerp`:

You can easily create a template that will do what you want:

```cpp
template<typename T>
[[nodiscard]] T lerp(const T& a, const T& b, float t) {
    return ((1.0f - t) * a) + (t * b);
}
```

Comment: or wait for [`std::lerp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lerp) to be implemented by your platform

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the `[[nodiscard]]` here? I can't really think of any mistake that this could possibly catch.

Comment: @Frank It's an [attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) that tells the compiler that it should warn you that you are not catching the return value in some way. It's a bug-catching feature.

Comment: @Caleth Absolutely. Using a provided STL feature is always preferred over writing your own. Prior to October 2016, `std::clamp` didn't exist so it was common for a dev to write their own. Now there's no reason to.

Comment: @Casey I know what it *is*, it just looks useless here. Can you please share an example of a bug that this would catch for that specific function? I'd be curious to see what that would look like since I can't come up with anything. From my PoV, this just adds a dependency on C++14 for what I feel is no good reason.

Comment: @Frank No example needed. Why would you call a function that returns a math result and then ignore it? It's liked calling `std::sqrt(x);` exactly like that. You just completely ignored the return value. This is always an unintended error. In this day-and-age, compiling for anything less than C++14 is a dumb idea. For MSVC, you literally [can't](https://twitter.com/stephantlavavej/status/1151977361207771136) use any mode lower than C++14.

Comment: @Casey How is that a bug though? It doesn't lead to an invalid program and gets optimized away. That's just imposing style at the function's call site, which is not the business of the function.

Comment: Ideally compilers would figure out if a pure function's return value is discarded and warn automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has the `c++11` tag, but it's worth mentioning that [`std::lerp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lerp) gets you halfway there if you are compiling in c++20.

Providing your own `lerp()` is reasonably simple. Here's a more complete implementation of the function proposed by @Casey:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Ta, typename Tb, typename Tt>
constexpr auto lerp(const Ta& a, const Tb& b, const Tt& t) {
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point_v<Tt>);
    assert(t >= Tt{0} && t <= Tt{1});
    
    return a + t * (b - a);
}

// c++11 version:

template<typename Ta, typename Tb, typename Tt>
constexpr auto lerp(const Ta& a, const Tb& b, const Tt& t) -> decltype(a + t * (b - a)) {
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<Tt>::value, "Tt must be a floating point type");
    // assert(t >= Tt{0} && t <= Tt{1}); //can't assert in constexpr code in C++11 :(

    return a + t * (b - a);
}
```

However, `lerp()` doesn't quite get you where you want.

> If I input 0.799999 and the range is 0 to 10, then the output should be 8.

You'd end up with a 7 since C++ rounds everything towards 0 by default. So you'll also have to manually round the value to the nearest integer. You *could* do this as part of the lerp, but `lerp()` has a fairly well defined *expected* behavior. Messing with that could lead to surprises.

It's better to create a seperate method for this that makes use of `lerp()` under the hood:

```
template<typename IntT, typename Tt>
constexpr IntT interpolateToNearest(const IntT& a, const IntT& b, const Tt& t) {
  static_assert(std::is_integral_v<IntT>);

  // There's a hidden implicit cast to IntT here.
  return std::round(lerp(a, b, t));
}

// c++11 version:

template<typename IntT, typename Tt>
constexpr IntT interpolateToNearest(const IntT& a, const IntT& b, const Tt& t) {
  static_assert(std::is_integral<IntT>::value, "IntT must be an integer type");
  return std::round(lerp(a, b, t));
}
```

Note that this enforces that `a`, `b`, and the return type all be the same type. That's a bit of an arbitrary decision, and something you may or may not want to change based on your needs.

usage:

```
int x = interpolateToNearest(0, 10, 0.5);
```

Comment: Won't that give different results than asker expects? They want an integral value in the target range, not a floating point value. For instance they expect `lerp(0, 10, 0.799999f)` to be `8`, not `7.99999`.

Comment: @NathanPierson `(int)ceil(lerp(0, 10, 0.799999f))` does the trick. The `ceil()` is something OP will have no choice but to do anyways.

Comment: I think it would actually be `round` not `ceil`, since they want `(0, 10, 0.345)` to go to `3` not `4`. Just wanted to point out that there's still a little bit of massaging needed to get the outputs exactly where asker wants them to be.

Comment: @NathanPierson Good catch. Updated the answer.

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer I've updated the answer with versions of the code that compile under c++11.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if C++11 or C++14 has anything to support this.